# receiving a file through curl webpy

Tags: python, web.py

i need to receive an file through CURL in webpy

```
import web
import json

class GetFile:

    def POST(self):
        try:
            i = web.input()
            data = web.data() 
        except Error(e):
            print e
```

I am not sure how to do this because there is no example to receive an data from CURL

```
curl -o -H "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -T doc.xml "http://localhost:8080/get_file
```

I am getting an issue

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Content-Type: text/html
Allow: GET
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 19 Oct 2012 11:54:13 GMT
Server: localhost
```

can any one give me an example code to upload an file through curl and save it in a location.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a file use urlib

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
html = response.read()
```

To upload a file, make sure to mark the contet as [multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean):

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" --data-binary @doc.xml http://localhost:2332/upload
```

Comment: I am not sure about your solution i am trying to make an API with webpy where i need to receive a file and give an respond for successive  receive

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137946/python-extracting-binary-from-a-post-request-using-web-py

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `-T` option to curl uses the PUT method by default, and you have only implemented a POST handler. You could try it with a `-X POST`, or investigate the `-d` and related options as alternatives to `-T`, which will use POST by default.

Or, you could add a PUT handler to your class, if it was your intention to use the PUT method to upload the files.